# MarshalJSON on array of structs with non standard field in Go

Tags: go

I have the following types:

```
type IPFilePair struct {
    IP net.IP
    FileName string
}

type IPFilePairs []*IPFilePair
```

I'm trying to marshal the JSON of this using `json.Marshal(sample_ipfilepairs)` but because `IP` isn't a string, it changes it into something strange.

What is the proper way to make the JSON of this output `IP` as a string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think if you have access to the definition of `IPFilePair`, creating local typedef of `net.IP` that you add `MarshanJSON()` to is the way to go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net"
    "fmt"
)

type netIP net.IP

type IPFilePair struct {
    IP netIP
    FileName string
}

type IPFilePairs []*IPFilePair

func (ip netIP) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(net.IP(ip).String())
}

func main() {
    pair1 := IPFilePair{netIP{127, 0, 0, 1}, "file1"}
    pair2 := IPFilePair{netIP{127, 0, 0, 2}, "file2"}
    sample_ipfilepairs := IPFilePairs{&pair1, &pair2}

    b, _ := json.Marshal(sample_ipfilepairs)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

This outputs:

```
[{"IP":"127.0.0.1","FileName":"file1"},{"IP":"127.0.0.2","FileName":"file2"}]
```

Of course, if you ever need to unmarshal that back into the same Go data structure, you'll want to implement `UnmarshalJSON()` on `netIP` using `net.ParseIP`.

I'm certainly curious if anyone knows of an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: It's a shame you can't just add the `MarshalJSON` method directly to `net.IP`, but I guess that is one of the restrictions needed to be able to compile modules separate from the full program.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge.  Agreed.  This is the best way I know how to do it, but I was kind of hoping someone more fluent in Go than I am would come along and show a simpler solution.

Comment: One alternative would be to implement your `MarshalJSON` method at the `IPFilePairs` level.  You could build a `map[string] interface{}` holding the stringified IP address and filename and marshal that.  That lets you use `net.IP` directly, but adds work everywhere you want to embed an IP address.